# HTML: element breakdown

Tags: html, tags

Suppose I have the following HTML element:

`<foo spam="eggs">bar</foo>`

I know that `foo` is the 'tag', but what are the technical names for `spam`, `eggs`, and `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spam="eggs"` is **attribute** (as a whole) and `bar` is the **child node**.
You can also break the attribute down to **attribute name** and **attribute value**.

Comment: This is the simplest and clearest response, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`spam` is an attribute name
`"eggs"` is the attribute `spam`'s value
and `bar` is a child node, in this case, a child of type textNode.  Children can also be "elements" (aka tags).

Read more on elements (aka tags) here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

And on attributes here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this one and the next chapter: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp
In any case, these are called attributes, values and content.
EDIT: whoa, ninjas abound.